# How to avoid taking rain damage as WX-78

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

I'm playing the reign of giants expansion as WX-78, and he's taking damage because he is wet.

It is raining, but I have an umbrella. However, **the "wetness" meter keeps going up**. How can I get dry? I'm dying!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Wetness):

> The player can dry themselves out faster by standing next to a fire. The rate of wetness can also be decreased, but not stopped, by standing under a Tree (including Birchnut Trees). This will decrease the amount of time waiting to lose the 'Wet' status. Standing under a Tree grants 40% Water Resistance.
>
> The best way to keep wetness low during Spring is to wear some **Water Resistant** gear. These items decrease the rate at which the player gets wet, and having more than one of them equipped provides a cumulative bonus. *The character stops getting wet when 100% water resistance is achieved, so the player will want to wear a combination of them that doesn't surpass 100% by too much. When 100% water resistance is achieved, any wetness previously had will start to lower until the player becomes completely dry.*

The Umbrella can't stop the rate at which the player gains Wetness, it will be slowed down because its water resistance factor is 90%.

Comment: Right! So an umbrella alone doesn't work, but when I wear a simple straw hat or football helmet, I stay dry.